# Selecting unique id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

Below is the replicas of the tables I have created. My goal is to simply pick the unique `id_num` from the First Table which is not found on the Second Table.

I have tried doing the code below but somehow, I kept getting empty results

```
SELECT `first_table`.name FROM `first_table`
INNER JOIN `second_table`
ON `first_table`.id_num = `second_table`.id_num
WHERE `first_table`.name = `second_table`.name
```

First Table:

```
   id_num   |  name
    301     |  Bobby
    123     |  George
    25      |  Vicky
```

Second Table:

```
   id_num   |  name
    301     |  Bobby
    435     |  George
    25      |  Vicky
```

My desire result I am looking for:

```
id_num   |  name
435     |  George
```

Comment: `id_num` in desired result should be `123` instead of `435` according to your requirement

Comment: do you need that `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3):

`LEFT JOIN` should work here.

```
SELECT `first_table`.name FROM `first_table`
LEFT JOIN `second_table`
ON `first_table`.id_num = `second_table`.id_num
WHERE `second_table`.id_num is NULL
```

See also this useful infographic

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this using `NOT IN`

```
select `id_num` , name from `table2` where name not in (
                                                  SELECT t1.name FROM `table1` t1
                                                  INNER JOIN `table2` t2
                                                  ON t1.id_num = t2.id_num )
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46934/9)

Comment: Why you should not use this construct ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46934/17  vs an indexed example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b773a/1 conclusion LEFT JOIN will scale better on an large number off records